# Basic question about set theory and dilations

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose we have an open ball $B_1 = B(0, \frac{1}{2} ) \subset X$ where $X$ is complete normed space. $B_1$ is open ball centered at $0$ of radius $\frac{1}{2}$. Does it follow that for a given $x \in X$, then $x \in k B_1$ for $k > 2 ||x|| $???

I am having hard time to see why this is true! I hope someone can help me. thanks

Comment: $\frac{1}{2} > k^{-1} ||x||$. Isn´t this your assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $x\in X$ be an arbitrary element. Since $k > 2 ||x||$, $\frac{1}{k}<\frac{1}{2||x||}$. So
$$||\frac{1}{k}.x||=\frac{1}{k}.||x||<\frac{||x||}{2||x||}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Therefore 
$$\frac{1}{k}.x \in B_1 = B(0, \frac{1}{2} ) $$
or
$$x \in k.B_1 $$